# How to start tweetsharp OAuth process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oauth, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

I am having trouble getting twitter to authorize my application with tweetsharp. I have my consumerKey and consumerSecret. It goes to the website and allows me to authorize. Then it loads nonstop. When I refresh, my app is on my authorized app list. How do I get my application to check if my app is already authorized? and once I do that how do I get my app to follow people or even just post?

Also how do I get the `Request["oauth"]` capability. When I type Request visual studio doesn't know what it is.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    service = new TwitterService("Consumer Key", "Consumer Secret");
    var token = service.GetRequestToken("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate");
    // Step 2 - Redirect to the OAuth Authorization URL
    // Pass your credentials to the service

    // Step 1 - Retrieve an OAuth Request Token
    //OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();

    // Step 2 - Redirect to the OAuth Authorization URL
    string url = service.GetAuthorizationUri(token).ToString();
    Process.Start(url);

    // Step 3 - Exchange the Request Token for an Access Token
   // string verifier = Console.ReadLine(); // <-- This is input into your application by your user
    OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessToken(token);

    // Step 4 - User authenticates using the Access Token
    service.AuthenticateWith(access.Token, access.TokenSecret);
}
```